# Any way to internationalize BIRT reports without property files

Tags: localization, internationalization, report, birt

BIRT supports l10n an i18n using simple property files. I'm running reports from Jboss and
my rptdesign files are stored in database. When creating design I'm providing InputStream

```
design = engine.openReportDesign(designStream);
```

I think there is no way to do the same with localization property files. This separation is quite inconvenient. **I'm wondering if there is any way to handle localization without property files?** For example from database. Or it would be great to store localization map in .rptdesign file.